# Does Z3py support Linear Temporal logic LTL?

Tags: z3, constraint-programming, z3py

Does Z3py support Linear Temporal logic LTL? 
If yes, can you provide an example of simple explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z3 does not support LTL or other temporal or modal logics. 
The input accepted by Z3 is first-order logic with theories, such as arithmetic.